# laravel 5.1 auth attempt login authenticaton

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am working in laravel 5 and having difficulties with my authentication login.

I cannot login (with correct user and pass) and get redirected again to the "login" page and not to the page that I want.

My table in phpmyadmin is called "users" so using Auth is right.

**Why doesn't it work?**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth; 

// product é a pasta e o index é a pagina 
class BackendControlador extends Controller {

    public function index() {

    $email = 'email';
    $password = 'password';

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'acesso' => 1])) {
             return redirect()->intended('backend/dashboard.index');
        } elseif (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $email, 'password' => $password, 'acesso' => 0])) {
            return redirect()->intended('welcome');
        } else {
            return view('auth/login');
        }
    }

    public function portfolio() { 
        return view('backend/portfolio.index'); 
    }       
}
```

**My routes code:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome'); 
});

Route::get('backend','BackendControlador@index');

Route::get('backend/portfolio','BackendControlador@portfolio');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Comment: please post your routes.php

Comment: could you mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems are

1. the lines of code are not taking the variables you send, so you will only get logged in if your username is equal to email and password equal to password in your database.

   ```
   $email = 'email';
   $password = 'password';
   ```

change it to something like

```
    $email  = Request::input('email'),
    $pass   = \Hash::make(Request::input('password'))
```

2. You will have to use Request

   ```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
   ```

or

```
    use Request;
```

3. As suggested in my comment use [bestmomo](https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold)

> 1. edit your json file to require
>
>    `"bestmomo/scafold": "dev-master"`
> 2. Update your composer with command
>
> `composer update`
>
> 3.The next required step is to add the service provider to config/app.php :
>
> `Bestmomo\Scafold\ScafoldServiceProvider::class,`
>
> 4. Publish
>
> `php artisan vendor:publish`

Comment: continues to refresh the page when I insert the user

Comment: maybe you could replace your redirects with texts for debugging purposes

Comment: not sure if you know https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold for easy scaffold of authorization

Comment: No, it's my first time. I'm just programming in laravel for 5 days. I'll take a look.

Comment: the composer is to be to sure?     
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "bestmomo/scafold": "dev-master",
    },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94267/discussion-between-davejal-and-jose-cerejo).

Comment: enter the chat, I will be available only 10 more minutes or else tommorow